# Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant for defining a number

Tags: c++, syntax, c-preprocessor

I'm new to C++, so I don't know what they mean with this error in a phidget-code example:

> Main.cpp:8:16: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

```
//verander de volgende informatie naar de informatie voor jouw database

#define dserver "oege.ie.hva.nl"
#define duser "username"
#define dpassword "password"
#define ddatabase "databasename"

#define homeid 1234 //line 8
```

Is there a syntax error? Or something else? I use #define instead of int.

EDIT: added full error log..

> complete error-log: http://pastebin.com/3vtbzmXD
>
> Full main.cpp code: http://pastebin.com/SDTz8vni

Comment: You'll need to show more of `Main.cpp`.

Comment: prefer `const int homeid = 1234;` over `define`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Indented directives are perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm curious what is on lines 1..7

Comment: @JosephMansfield You may be thinking of pre-standard C compilers, which did not always support it, but the very first C standard and the very first C++ standard both allow it.

Comment: @JosephMansfield The main is 370 line of code, I don't know what to show more. There is a lot of Libraries included and MySQL log-in data defined at line 3-15

Comment: @WhozCraig added those lines...

Comment: Now you just need to provide the *complete* and *unedited* error output.

Comment: yeah, there isn't anything wrong with that at all [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/wt1Qoc). I suspect we're not getting the whole, shocking story. I concur with had below.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've now added the full error log..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've now added the full error log

Comment: Hvd is definitely correct then. You're essentially writing: string 1234; which is obviously not valid C++.

Comment: Add the error log in the question, not as an attachment; that link will die eventually

Comment: Remember that the preprocessor will just replace macros everywhere it finds them. So having e.g. a declaration `string homeid;` will result in `string 1234;` after preprocessing, which is not valid.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The full error is

```
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 note: in expansion of macro ‘homeid’
string homeid;
       ^
```

You're trying to declare a variable with the same name as a macro, but that can't be done. The preprocessor has already stomped over the program, turning that into `string 1234;`, which is not a valid declaration. The preprocessor has no knowledge of the program structure, and macros don't follow the language's scope rules.

Where possible, use language features like constants and inline functions rather than macros. In this case, you might use

```
const int homeid = 1234;
```

This will be scoped in the global namespace, and can safely be hidden by something with the same name in a narrower scope. Even when hidden, it's always available as `::homeid`.

When you really need a macro, it's wise to follow the convention of using `SHOUTY_CAPS` for macros. As well as drawing attention to the potential dangers and wierdnesses associated with macro use, it won't clash with any name using other capitalisation.

Comment: I have much less errors now, but now I have new one which is this: error: expected initializer before numeric constant
 const int homeid 1234

Comment: @Kil'jaeden: You missed out the `=` between the variable name and the initialiser.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it... I do have another error, but that does not have to do with this.

Comment: I got this failure when people were using things like "CONST" as a part of their name but the windows.h file was overriding it with a macro.  `#undef` got rid of it...weird...

Answer (score 12):

That line is fine.

What is most likely happening is that the compiler is complaining not about the macro definition itself, but about the *use* of the macro. Example:

```
#define homeid 1234

void homeid() {
}
```

When compiling this with GCC, I get:

```
so.cc:1:16: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 #define homeid 1234
                ^
so.cc:3:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘homeid’
 void homeid() {
      ^
```

This tells you that the numeric constant prompting the complaint is part of the macro definition, but also that that macro is *used* (in this case seemingly by accident) on line 3. Take a look at where the macro expansion is coming from in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when the defined numeric constant is also declared elsewhere in the code. For instance, declared like below and called outside any class or function.

```
    #define MODEL_SELECT_PLOWMAN
    
    ....
    
    MODEL_SELECT_PLOWMAN


    void someFunc(){
       ...
    }
```

in this particular case, `#define homeid 1234` is declared correctly however `homeid` is most likely misplaced and repeated within the code (and without `#define`)