# unqualified id with Eigen class

Tags: c++, eigen

there seems to be a problem with the following code. I get the error message

> error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
>
> Eigen::Matrix M_inv1_abc = pose_l.block<3, 3>(0,
>   0).inverse();
>   This is a code sample:

```
template<typename T> 
Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 1>  Function(Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 4> pose_l)
{

// fails here
Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 3> M_inv1 = pose_l.block<3, 3>(0, 0).inverse();

// this works, sample is from https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html 
Eigen::MatrixXf m(4,4);
Eigen::MatrixXf y(2,2);
m <<  1, 2, 3, 4,
      5, 6, 7, 8,
      9,10,11,12,
     13,14,15,16;
y = m.block<2,2>(1,1);

}
```

With the sample MatrixXf I don't use my template...

I renamed pose_l and M_inv1; in other posts, like
[Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant for defining a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524755/expected-unqualified-id-before-numeric-constant-for-defining-a-number)
a redefinition helped, but not in my case.

What am I missing?

Best 
ManuKlause

Comment: See this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicTemplateKeyword.html), you need to add the template keyword before block: `pose_l.template block<3, 3>(0, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I would like to mark your post as solution, how can I do that (new in this forum...)

Answer (score 3):

```
pose_l.template block<3, 3>(0, 0).inverse();
```

For detail, you can refer to how c++ deduce the type of variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this (adding parentheses around the block sub-expression):

```
template<typename T> 
Eigen::Matrix<T, 4, 1> Function(Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 4> pose_l)
{
    Eigen::Matrix<T, 3, 3> M_inv1 = (pose_l.block<3, 3>(0, 0)).inverse();
    // ...
}
```